# Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) for incremental/online learning

Tags: optimization, hyperparameter, online-algorithms

As stated in the title, is there a way to adapt PSO to an online scenario where new data samples arrive continuously?

In more detail: suppose that I have a classifier with several parameters for which the optimal values are to be chosen automatically, instead of being predefined. I want to use PSO to select the parameters. I know this is doable in a static scenario, where the data set is fixed. However, if new data samples arrive over time (and in large amounts), is there a way to make PSO work on such dynamic data streams?

Also, I am open to other ways to implement self-adaptive parameters. PSO is a possible choice but if it's not possible I'd love to hear your suggestions about other approaches.

Thank you!!! :-)